# Erro ao instalar Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Galera, estou com o seguinte erro ao instalar o Android Studio:

[image]

Eu ja configurei a variavel,e ja ta instalado o JDK

Mesmo assim, o erro persiste!

Comment: Ja fiz todo processo, e continua dando o mesmo erro. Minha versão é a 8.0.91 do JDK. Ja instalei todas as variaveis! Ta osso!

Answer (score 0):

Preste muita tenção, baixe a IDE Android Studio mais atual, e baixe seu JDK conforme a sua máquina 32bits ou 64bits, para que sua instalação dê certo, como saber se sua máquina é 32bits ou 64bits?

> Tecle `windows + r` e digite `control` e tecle enter, agora vá em
>   Sistema e lá você saberá e terá a informação.

Outra coisa importante:

- Em Sistema
- Configurações Avançadas do Sistema
- Propriedades do Sistema
- Avançado
- Variáveis de Ambiente

> Se você tem `- Variáveis de usuário -` iguais as `- Variáveis do sistema -` sua instalação sempre dará erro, exclua as `- Variáveis de usuário -` erradas e inclua só aquelas do tutorial em `- Variáveis do sistema -`, como visto abaixo.

### -- Modo Errado --

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### -- Modo Correto --

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cuidado também com duplicatas de JDK em, `Valor da variável`, exemplo:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program Files\Algum
>   Software;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_41\bin;

Mantenha só o JDK mais atual, não duplique as entradas no `Valor da variável`, assim:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program Files\Algum Software;

Quer dizer o valor de seu JDK, só aparece uma vez em cada variável!

Comment: Ja fiz isso tudo, e continua dando o erro. Não sei o que faço mais. Ja li de tudo na internet